# fprintf to output file not mirroring what is in source file

Tags: c

I'm learning to code. I'm trying to print from one file to a next,but the results are not exactly as the source file. I tried rubber ducking but can't find the problem. I don't understand why it's not printing the results exactly,well except the zero. Below is the contents of source file exam.txt

```
BECDCBAADEBACBAEDDBE
456  CBAEXCDABECXDEABCDEA
567  ECABXCDEBAEDBADCEBAC
234  JHGVCDDGF
764  JHGGVVFD
0
```

This is the code that I thought should work. Got no warning messages or anything

```
FILE*in=fopen("exam.txt","r");
FILE*out=fopen("output.txt","w");
char answer[100][20],correct[20];
int candidate[100];
fscanf(in,"%s",correct);
int j=0;
fscanf(in,"%d %s",&candidate[j],answer[j]);
while(candidate[j]!=0)
    {j++;fscanf(in,"%d %s",&candidate[j],answer[j]);}
fprintf(out,"%s\n",correct);
for(int r=0;r<j;r++)fprintf(out,"%d   %s\n",candidate[r],answer[r]);
fclose(in);
fclose(out);
```

But this is the output that I'm getting

```
BECDCBAADEBACBAEDDBECBAEXCDABECXDEABCDEAECABXCDEBAEDBADCEBACJHGVCDDGF
456   CBAEXCDABECXDEABCDEAECABXCDEBAEDBADCEBACJHGVCDDGF
567   ECABXCDEBAEDBADCEBACJHGVCDDGF
234   JHGVCDDGF
764   JHGGVVFD
```

I tried rubber ducking, but just can't figure out why it's printing out subsequent lines with previous lines.

Comment: `BECDCBAADEBACBAEDDBE` This has 20 characters. Storing it as a C string requires 21 characters (including the nul terminator) so `fscanf` overruns the receiving buffers of length `20`.

Comment: I changed it to 21 and it worked thanks